# Android Studio - logcat filter created automatically after running app

Tags: android-studio, logcat

When I started programming this week with Android Studio, I was wondering why the logcat debug window shows no output.
After some checking I saw that I had a filter active which was hiding the logcast output.
After switching the filter to "No filters", the logcat output was visible.

So, I deleted this filter.
After running the app again, the logcat was empty again - and again the reason was the filter, which was re-created at the time I started the app.

The filter created is named

```
app: com.xyz.my_app
```

and it's only option set is

```
By package name: com.xyz.my_app
```

So my question is: Is it normal that this filter is created after running an app, and why does it prevent logcat to show anything?

I'm little confused because I'm sure I didn't had this behaviour at the end of last week..logcat was showing the logs without the need to set the filter to "No filters" manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer in the following post:

[Logcat cannot detect app or package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504822/logcat-cannot-detect-app-or-package-names?rq=1)

That a filter is created every time an application is run seems to be normal.
The problem that logcat couldn't filter the logs was  because the package name in the log output was missing.
This can be solved by enable "Tools > Android > Enable ADB integration". (as stated by user Gak2 in the comments of the question...)

I guess I disabled this somehow unintentionally, that would explain why the logging stopped to work from day to day.