# Android Studio Log Cat not showing Application Package

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat

I updated to Android Studio  1.2.1.1, I was using Eclipse earlier, and log cat worked perfect on it. Since I have moved to Android Studio, I am not able to filter my log cat by my application (package), Eclipse used to show all package name(s), where as in Android Studio I am getting none. I am attaching screen shot of log cat. I also restarted Android Studio, and ran project several times, but it remains the same.

[image]

Comment: you can use the filter setting for customizing logcat
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logcat cannot detect app or package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504822/logcat-cannot-detect-app-or-package-names)